# NixOS, Can't get display to work from 4070 TI and Boot into Text caused by Enabling Nvidia Video Drivers

Tags: nvidia, nixos

I’m trying to set up my new build to use the GPU for the display output instead of the built-in display of the motherboard and I can’t seem to get it to work. That is to say that when I plug in a display port or HDMI cable from my GPU to a monitor, no input is detected from the monitor. When I connect the monitor to the mobo’s built-in display port or HDMI, it works fine.

I’ve followed the Nvidia setup documentation including the "Boot to Text" section in the manual. However, when I run `sudo nixos-rebuild boot` and then `sudo reboot`, it boots into a screen with a cursor in the top left. I can switch to another tty to get a login screen where I can login and edit the configuration.nix file.

What I’ve been able to do is to isolate the line in the title, this one:

```
  services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia" ];
```

to be the line that is causing the problem. When I have that line commented out, the GUI starts fine (I’m using Plasma). When I uncomment the line, I get that hanging boot.

For diagnosis, my system is this (note the 4070 TI is found as a device by the OS):

```
 mikelane@nixos 
 --------------
 OS: NixOS 23.05.3376.4c8cf44c5b94 (Stoat) x86_64
 Host: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI
 Kernel: 6.1.51
 Uptime: 11 hours, 20 mins
 Packages: 1029 (nix-system), 566 (nix-user)
 Shell: bash 5.2.15
 Resolution: 3840x2160
 DE: Plasma
 WM: KWin
 Icons: kora [GTK2/3] 
 Terminal: .konsole-wrappe
 CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X3D (32) @ 4.200GHz
 GPU: AMD ATI Raphael
 GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Ti
 Memory: 5428MiB / 127956MiB
```

And the log output of the last failing boot (`journalctl -b -1`) can be found on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/CDwG2zx8). My configuration.nix file is on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/ApbswGhK).

If anyone can help me figure out how to make it so I get a monitor signal from my GPU, I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Did get this working? I have the same issue